# Fontawesome arrow will be moved when I hover the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.b_btnWrapp .btn.btn_default:after {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
}

.b_btnWrapp .btn.btn_default:after:hover {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="b_btnWrapp btn btn_default">CLick</button>
```

I want the arrow to move the right side of the button using CSS AFTER concept.

Comment: Please properly format your code. Note that the code you gave should also [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not sure what effect you're after, but there are several things wrong with your code. If you want the icon to be inside the button, the button needs to have `position:relative`. To target the button itself, you need `.b_btnWrapp.btn.btn_default` for a selector, without spaces. If you want to change the icon when hovering the button, replace `:after:hover` with `:hover::after`. Etc. But as I said, I don't know what you're after, so I can't post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove backspace in a style selector, because it's get interpreted as "`.btn.btn_default` is a child of `.b_btnWrapp`".

Just use this code and it will work

```css
.b_btnWrapp {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.b_btnWrapp:after {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f061";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 15px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.b_btnWrapp:hover:after {
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button class="b_btnWrapp btn btn_default">CLick</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Also notice, that I simplified your code a bit (removed unnecessary complexity in selectors and removed duplicated code). Don't forget to use `position:relative` on a parent if you want to use track `absolute` position of a child in parent "coordinates". And have an attention on order. `.element:hover:after` is not same to `.element:after:hover`

Answer (score 0):

> Try to add this in your style

```
.b_btnWrapp.btn.btn_default:after {
      content: "\f054";
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
      font-weight: 900;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 30px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

    .b_btnWrapp.btn.btn_default:after:hover {
      top: 15px;
      right: 18px;
    }
```

Comment: That won't work, because the extra space is only one of the problems in the OP's code. See also the other answer that addresses more of the problems.

Comment: So you want to move arrow when user clicks on button

Answer (score 0):

I made the toggling of arrow using javascript. Hope it helps!

```js
var icon=document.querySelector("#btn i");

function toggleArrow(){
  var isLeftArrow=icon.classList.contains("fa-chevron-left");
  if(isLeftArrow){
    icon.classList.add("fa-chevron-right");
    icon.classList.remove("fa-chevron-left");
  }else{
    icon.classList.add("fa-chevron-left");
    icon.classList.remove("fa-chevron-right");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-r/k8YTFqmlOaqRkZuSiE9trsrDXkh07mRaoGBMoDcmA58OHILZPsk29i2BsFng1B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-4aon80D8rXCGx9ayDt85LbyUHeMWd3UiBaWliBlJ53yzm9hqN21A+o1pqoyK04h+" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="btn" class="b_btnWrapp btn btn_default" onclick="toggleArrow()">
  Click 
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
</button>
```